# Vue fetching data ,query parameter not working

Tags: vue.js, fetch, fetch-api, lichess

### Problem

I am using the [Lichess API](https://lichess.org/api#operation/apiGamesUser) where it is stated under *Get Export games of a user* that the query parameter `max` is of type integer and can be set `>= 1`.

In the following snippet of code I am not able to fetch data with `max` larger than 1, but it works for `max=1`. It also does not work in this identical [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ranjbz9t/4/), nor in my VsCode project. They work *only if* I set the query `max` to the value 1.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    temp: 1
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch(
         `https://lichess.org/api/games/user/Thibault?max=2&rated=false`, 
         {headers:{
            Accept:'application/x-ndjson'
          }}
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <button @click="fetchData()"> fetch data</button>
</div>
```

### Things I have tried

I have tried using `async await`, and removing them but with no success, I have tried to search online for solutions and read the API documentation thoroughly but it just doesn't work.

the Network devtools says the `content-type` is x-ndjson so I set `application/x-ndjson` in my `header` tag (solving another first problem  I had before).

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming data format is [nd-json](http://ndjson.org/) and [Lichess API](https://lichess.org/api#section/Introduction/Streaming-with-ND-JSON) offers a [utility function](https://gist.github.com/ornicar/a097406810939cf7be1df8ea30e94f3e) to help reading NDJSON streamed responses.

If you use this, you will get the data:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    temp: 1
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch(
         `https://lichess.org/api/games/user/Thibault?max=2&rated=false`, 
         {headers:{
            Accept:'application/x-ndjson'
          }}
      ).then(readStream(onMessage))
       .then(onComplete);

      console.log(arr);
    },
  }
})

const readStream = processLine => response => {
  const stream = response.body.getReader();
  const matcher = /\r?\n/;
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  let buf = '';

  const loop = () =>
    stream.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
      if (done) {
        if (buf.length > 0) processLine(JSON.parse(buf));
      } else {
        const chunk = decoder.decode(value, {
          stream: true
        });
        buf += chunk;

        const parts = buf.split(matcher);
        buf = parts.pop();
        for (const i of parts.filter(p => p)) processLine(JSON.parse(i));
        return loop();
      }
    });

  return loop();
}
const arr = [];
const onMessage = obj => arr.push(obj);
const onComplete = () => console.log('The stream has completed');
```